# How to convert Flask {{ }} {% %} syntax into ASP.NET equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, jinja2

I wrote some code in Flask that I'm trying to convert into ASP.NET as that is what the larger website is written in, and I'm not sure how to convert this simple syntax from Flask to ASP.NET.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td> First Name </td>
        <td> Last Name </td>
    </tr>
    {% for i in range(5) %}
    <tr>
        <td id="fn_{{i}}">{{i}}</td>
        <td id="ln_{{i}}">{{i}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

What is the C# equivalent of {% and {{ in this context? I've seen that <% %> might be it, but I'm not sure how to use it. I've tried the following, but the variable "i" goes out of scope when I try and use it.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td> First Name </td>
        <td> Last Name </td>
    </tr>
    <% for (int i=0;i<5;i++) %>
    <tr>
        <td id="fn_<% i %>"><% i %></td>
        <td id="ln_<% i %>"><% i %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The syntax you attribute to Flask is actually the [Jinja2 templating language](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/), and is just a simple loop over the values 0 through 4 inclusive.

Comment: You are missing `{` and `}` of the `for` block.

Comment: I assume you're using webforms instead of Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add some parentheses. The missing brackets is why your variable goes out of scope.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td> First Name </td>
        <td> Last Name </td>
    </tr>
    <% for (int i=0;i<5;i++) { %>   <!-- added parenthesis here -->
    <tr>
        <td id="fn_<%= i %>"><%= i %></td>
        <td id="ln_<%= i %>"><%= i %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>  <!-- and here -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use it like this. But I'm not a fan. The code becomes hard to read. If you use Webforms better use a GridView or Repeater. In Razor it becomes much better to implement a for-loop inline.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>First Name </td>
        <td>Last Name </td>
    </tr>
    <% for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %>
    <tr>
        <td id="fn_<%= i %>"><%= i %></td>
        <td id="ln_<%= i %>"><%= i %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```